# seconds since date to date in R

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, lubridate, seconds

I have a dataset file with a time variable in "seconds since 1981-01-01 00:00:00". What I need is to convert this time into calendar date (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss). I've seen a lot of different ways to do this for time since epoch (1970) (timestamp, calendar.timegm, etc) but I'm failing to do this with a different reference date.

Comment: With `lubridate` package you can try `as_datetime(x, origin = "1981-01-01")` where `x` is number in seconds. Or you can just try `as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1981-01-01")` in base R.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply add 347133600s (11 years) to each value in seconds. this will then allow you to simply use conversion as it would be from 1970-01-01.